# Recursively assign the left side of a list with the label "left" and the right with the label "right" in python

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a question I am working on in interview prepping. Please advise with the logic. 
If I am given a list with either strings or lists, always 2 elements so either element order=0 or element order=1, how can i recursively assign left side and concatenate it with "left="+element and right side with "right="+element.. e.g.

```
l7 = [1,[[2,3],4]]
[left=1,right=[left=[left=2,right=3],right=4]]
```

I managed to sum recursively using the algorithm below. However, assigning labels is a bit challenging.

```
def addList(l:list):
    sumValues = 0
    for x in range(len(l)):
        print("\nx: " +str(x)+" data:"+str(l[x]))
        if type(l[x]) == list:
            print("type is list")
            sumValues+=addList(l[x])
            print("sumValues = "+str(sumValues))
        else:
            sumValues+=l[x]
            print("sumValues = "+str(sumValues))
    return sumValues
```

I am changing it to:

```
def addList(l:list):
    sumValues = ""
    for x in range(len(l)):
        print("\nx: " +str(x)+" data:"+str(l[x]))
        if type(l[x]) == list:
            print("type is list")
            if x ==0:
                sumValues += "left = "+ str(l[x])+str(sumValues)
                #print("left = "+str(sumValues))
            if x ==1:
                sumValues += "right = "+ str(l[x])+str(sumValues)
                print("right = "+str(sumValues))
        else:
            if x ==0:
                sumValues += "left = "+ str(l[x])+str(sumValues)
                #print("left = "+str(sumValues))
            if x ==1:
                sumValues += "right = "+ str(l[x])+str(sumValues)
                #print("right = "+str(sumValues))
    return sumValues

l7 = [1,[[2,3],4]]
addList(l7)
```

Results I get:
'left = 1right = [[2, 3], 4]left = 1'

Comment: Your problem statement is unintelligible. You'll need to provide a more precise specification of the task you want to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
def addList(l:list,sumValues):
    for x in range(len(l)):
        #print("\nx: " +str(x)+" data:"+str(l[x]))
        if type(l[x]) == list:
            #print("type is list")
            sumValues += "[left = "
            sumValues = addList(l[x],sumValues)
            if x==0:
                sumValues += ", right = "
        else:
            if x ==0:
                sumValues += str(l[x])+", right = "

            if x ==1:
                sumValues += str(l[x])+"]"
    return sumValues

l7 = [1,[[2,3],4]]
sumValues = "[left = "
print(addList(l7,sumValues))
```